# How can we get current rendering stream details in Shaka player?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mse, shaka

getStats() [api](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.extern.html#.Stats) provides the current variant being downloaded. Is there a way

1. To get the current rendering variant?
2. Get notified when rendering variant gets changed ?

Both of these are available in hls.js.

Comment: Hi! Did you find the answer to this question of yours? I'm having the same problem. I need a way to get the currently-playing variant, and and an event for when it changes.

Comment: The code below worked for me, two years back.

Answer (score 0):

AdaptationEvent now has oldTrack and newTrack on it. You should be able to get all the necessary information off of those Track objects.

https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.Player.html#.event:AdaptationEvent
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.extern.html#.Track

Answer (score -2):

This code would work. We iterator over the available rendition and log the rendition which is currently active (used).

```
// This is for bitrate change due to ABR
shakaPlayer.addEventListener('adaptation', onAdaptationChange);

//This is for bitrate change made by user
shakaPlayer.addEventListener('variantchanged', onAdaptationChange);

function onAdaptation(event){
    var tracks = shakaPlayerInstance.getVariantTracks();
    for (iterator = 0; iterator < tracks.length; iterator++){
      if (tracks[iterator].active){
        console.log("Bandwidth: " + tracks[iterator].bandwidth);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```